# Scala SortedMap : Get all keys greater than a given key

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Given a Scala `collection.SortedMap` and a key `k`, what is the *most efficient way* of getting all keys (or even better, all *key-value pairs*) greater than `k` stored in the sorted map. The returned set of keys should preserve the order of keys.
Of course, I would like to avoid to peruse the whole data structure (i.e. using `filterKeys`), and take advantage of the fact that the map is sorted.

I would like to do something like :

```
val m = collection.SortedMap((1,1) -> "somevalue", (1,2) -> "somevalue", 
  (1,3) -> "somevalue", (2,1) -> "somevalue", (3,1) -> "somevalue")
m.getKeysGreaterThan((2,1))
// res0: scala.collection.SortedSet[(Int, Int)] = TreeSet((2,1), (3,1))
```

If you can think of a more appropriate map-like data structure, please suggest it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Try this from the API doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMap):

```
m.from((2,1))
```

Note, that the result is *inclusive* the key value.

I just checked in Scala 2.10, `TreeMap.from` calls `from` on `RedBlackTree`, which appears to be an efficient implementation (the usual O(log n) for tree-based data-structures).

Comment: Oh thank you, I must be totally dumb. I have been browsing scaladoc and SO for one hour to find the answer to this question...

Comment: There are also other similar methods namely `iteratorFrom`, `keysIteratorFrom` and `valuesIteratorFrom` that might be even more performant for certain use-cases. e.g. API doc for  `iteratorFrom`:  _x.iteratorFrom(y) is equivalent to but often more efficient than x.from(y).iterator_