# Scala SortedMap - iteratorFrom & co missing counterpart?

Tags: scala, iterator, scala-collections, sortedmap

## Retrieve entries belonging to greater keys

I recently stumbled upon a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14961566/3041008) asking how to retrieve keys greater than a given key in a `SortedMap`. AfaIk, these [`SortedMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMap) methods are of note:

- `from(from: A): SortedMap[A, B]`

  > Creates a ranged projection of this collection with no upper-bound
- `iteratorFrom(start: A): Iterator[(A, B)]`

  > Creates an iterator over all the key/value pairs contained in this map having a key greater than or equal to start according to the ordering of this map. x.iteratorFrom(y) is equivalent to but often more efficient than x.from(y).iterator.
- `keysIteratorFrom(start: A): Iterator[A]`

  > Creates an iterator over all the keys(or elements) contained in this collection greater than or equal to start according to the ordering of this collection. x.keysIteratorFrom(y) is equivalent to but often more efficient than x.from(y).keysIterator.
- `valuesIteratorFrom(start: A): Iterator[B]`

  > Creates an iterator over all the values contained in this map that are associated with a key greater than or equal to start according to the ordering of this map. x.valuesIteratorFrom(y) is equivalent to but often more efficient than x.from(y).valuesIterator.

## Retrieve entries belonging to smaller keys

In order to retrieve keys lesser than a given key you can use these [`SortedMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMap) methods (afaIk):

- `to(to: A): SortedMap[A, B]`

  > Create a range projection of this collection with no lower-bound

**Question:**
Why are there no analogue methods `iteratorTo`, `keysIteratorTo` and `valuesIteratorTo`?
How would they work, if they existed?:

- Would they iterate backwards from highest key to lowest key? (this makes more sense to me)
- Or would they iterate forwards from the lowest key to highest key?
  In this case you could get these iterators by do something like `sortedMap.to(_).iterator()`, although implementations of SortedMap could provide more efficient implementations of `iteratorTo` & co (analogue to `iteratorFrom` & co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the start fixed at the lowest key, takeWhile suffices:

```
scala> val m = TreeMap((0 to 10) map (i => (i, ('a' + i).toChar)) : _*)
m: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,Char] = Map(0 -> a, 1 -> b, 2 -> c, 3 -> d, 4 -> e, 5 -> f, 6 -> g, 7 -> h, 8 -> i, 9 -> j, 10 -> k)

scala> m.iterator.takeWhile(_._1 < 5)
res1: Iterator[(Int, Char)] = non-empty iterator

scala> .toList
res2: List[(Int, Char)] = List((0,a), (1,b), (2,c), (3,d), (4,e))
```

Comment: That solves iteration from lowest key to specific key. How would one go about iterating backwards from given key to lowest key efficiently?